# Quantum entanglement and special relativity PARADOX

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, time, quantum-entanglement

Imagine two entangled atomic clocks. After we entangle them, we measure the time: it does has to be the same , right ?

Now lets suppose that we entangle them , **but don't measure them**, then we plant one clock on the ground and put the other on a jumbo jet airplane and fly.

Now , in mid flight , we measure one of the clocks , it comes out as 1 second. this means that the other will also measure 1 sec.

***But how can it be that the clocks measure the same time if special relativity predicts time dialation ?!***

Comment: Who says the clock on the ground will measure the same as the other one? Entanglement is a type of correlation, but it doesn't imply they are identical. -1.

Answer (score 4):

Entanglement is about particle quantum states, e.g. spin up and down. Time is not a quantum state, it's a dimension of spacetime. There's not such a thing as "two entangled atomic clocks". There are "synchronized" atomic clocks, which is quite a different thing. If one of the clocks "travels" in spacetime (suffers accelerations) and comes back, GR predicts it will measure less time than the one that didn't travel, thus synchronization will be lost.

Answer (score 1):

Entanglement experiment performed in one frame of reference guarantees that the two measured results are synchronized in this frame of reference. If we try to perform the same entangled experiment while the two ends of the same length fiber optic lines are attached to two frames of references moving with a constant relative velocity, the two measured results will not be synchronized in either of the reference frames. We can synchronize both clocks when they are on the ground, but we cannot do it while one of them is in flight. Synchronizing both clocks on the ground does not even require entanglement - we can just put them in the same coordinate and synchronize them there.